# How to automatically open HTML select menu on an iPad

Tags: javascript, ipad, html-select

I have a suburb lookup utility [on my website](http://www.vulytrampolines.com/catalogue), where you put in a suburb or a postcode *(Australian only e.g. 4000, 2000, Brisbane, Sydney etc)* and it returns the resulting suburb/state/postcode (zip) in a select menu like so:

```
<select size="4" name="contact_suburb_list" id="contact_suburb_list">
<option value="0">CLEVELAND, NSW 2530</option>
<option value="1">CLEVELAND, QLD 4163</option>
<option value="2">CLEVELAND, TAS 7211</option>
<option value="3">CLEVELAND CROSSING, NSW 2469</option>
</select>
```

This works perfectly fine on desktops etc, but on mobile devices such as iPads... well, it seems iPad's don't really support the **size** attribute. It just shows an empty list item (not a tall one showing 4 options like it does on desktops).

Clicking on the empty list brings up the list items, so I was just wondering... how can I make that pop out list automatically display on iPads? I've tried clicking on the select, focussing on it, focussing on its first option child etc... doesn't seem to work... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the selected attribute on one option (probably the first one) should at least mean that one is selected by default.

```
<select size="4" name="contact_suburb_list" id="contact_suburb_list">
  <option value="0" selected>CLEVELAND, NSW 2530</option>
  <option value="1">CLEVELAND, QLD 4163</option>
  ...
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks, I did make one selected by default, but instead I just made a 'Please select suburb' option for only mobile devices. That made it work well. I couldn't get the list to automatically appear though, so its just a normal drop down.